# Is there a natural distance between skew hermitian matrices?

Tags: matrices, matrix-theory, linear-algebra

Working in machine learning, I try to find a way to compare time series, which can be considered as semi-continuous matrices belonging to $\mathbb R^{n \times \mathbb R}$ (a column corresponds to n-dimensional the value of the time series at a given time). A first step would be to consider the Gramian of the time series $u \in \mathbb R^{n \times \mathbb R}$: $M(u) = u.u' \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ (where $'$ is the transpose operator and $.$ is the integration along time). The good point is that $M(u)$ is semi-definite positive and that there is a natural Riemannian distance on the space of positive definite matrices (see the first pages of [this paper](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3awGCZsql0ZeUJ%3aciteseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi%3D10.1.1.158.3256%26rep%3Drep1%26type%3Dpdf+&hl=en&gl=de&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESjqPtGbpe8wxpjdywnQyRzlE-hIft1fgiMJQFdaI4Y4nB8tIuSyLki_n7fCkYv-oFpoz_jwYCLXll61QzcLcCbTjjWuxzwcTqkxvVp2B_02jCW2iN4SN6B8HdIHkqU5goXM9C3X&sig=AHIEtbQOTAAsUkl7urPeAUAGbJNnNjNr0g&pli=1) for a short intro):
$$d(M,N) = \|Log(M^{-1}.N) \|_{\mbox{Froebenius}}$$
This is an idea to measure the similarity between the two time series.

For some (convoluted) reason, I am now interested in the matrices of the form $P(u) = u.A.u' \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$, where $A$ can be seen as a skew-symmetric matrix of $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R \times \mathbb R}$. So I have two questions:

1. Is there a natural distance on the set of skew symmetric (or skew hermitian) matrices? I guess the answer is "not in such a general framework". Thus my second question is:
2. In the more particular case presented above: $P(u)$ is a Gram-like skew symmetric matrix, do we have such a distance? Note that $A$ is the same for all the time series we want to compare.

Comment: Actually the distance for posdef matrices is: $\|\log(M^{-1/2}NM^{-1/2})\|_F$...

Comment: I don't know if that is a natural distance, but a non-boring choice is given by mapping skew-Hermitian matrices to unitary matrices by using the exponential map, and then just using the Riemannian distance in the mapped space.

Answer (score 4):

Since skew-Hermitian matrices form the Lie algebra of the unitary group $U(n)$, the space has a natural positive definite inner product given by
$$
(A, B) = - tr (AB).
$$
This inner product, of course, defines a distance.  The inner product is invariant under conjugation by elements of $U(n)$.

Real skew-symmetric matrices form the Lie algebra of the orthogonal group.  It also has a conjugation invariant positive definite inner product, in fact only one up to a scalar multiple.  It is also $-tr(AB)$.

Comment: Isn't it the Frobenius norm?

Comment: Up to a scaler the inner product is the Killing form.  I don't know that the corresponding norm is called.

Comment: I mean, this construction should give the "trivial" norm $\left(\sum_{i,j} A_{ij}^2\right)^{1/2}$, if I am not missing something.